# JSON request android error

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

when receiving my json from my loop it comes as one big object 
how do I prevent this can someone point me in the right direction or documents.

Log....

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"1":{"id":1,"name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","website_slug":"bitcoin","rank":1,"circulating_supply":17153487,"total_supply":17153487,"max_supply":21000000,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":6720.93,"volume_24h":4367200000,"market_cap":115287385383,"percent_change_1h":-0.09,"percent_change_24h":2.07,"percent_change_7d":3.26}},"last_updated":1531828586},"1027":{"id":1027,"name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH","website_slug":"ethereum","rank":2,"circulating_supply":100744923,"total_supply":100744923,"max_supply":null,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":472.777,"volume_24h":1774520000,"market_cap":47629882298,"percent_change_1h":-0.45,"percent_change_24h":0.3,"percent_change_7d":5.32}},"last_updated":1531828591},"52":{"id":52,"name":"XRP","symbol":"XRP","website_slug":"ripple","rank":3,"circulating_supply":39262444717,"total_supply":99991916481,"max_supply":100000000000,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":0.473278,"volume_24h":269811000,"market_cap":18582051311,"percent_change_1h":-0.18,"percent_change_24h":2.43,"percent_change_7d":4.17}},"last_updated":1531828571},"1831":{"id":1831,"name":"Bitcoin Cash","symbol":"BCH","website_slug":"bitcoin-cash","rank":4,"circulating_supply":17242013,"total_supply":17242013,"max_supply":21000000,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":793.963,"volume_24h":471637000,"market_cap":13689519971,"percent_change_1h":-0.47,"percent_change_24h":3.58,"percent_change_7d":12.07}},"last_updated":1531828592},"1765":{"id":1765,"name":"EOS","symbol":"EOS","website_slug":"eos","rank":5,"circulating_supply":896149492,"total_supply":900000000,"max_supply":1000000000,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":7.94815,"volume_24h":666448000,"market_cap":7122730586,"percent_change_1h":-0.29,"percent_change_24h":2.5,"percent_change_7d":6.31}},"last_updated":1531828590},"2":{"id":2,"name":"Litecoin","symbol":"LTC","website_slug":"litecoin","rank":6,"circulating_supply":57444758,"total_supply":57444758,"max_supply":84000000,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":83.7447,"volume_24h":283495000,"market_cap":4810693998,"percent_change_1h":-0.17,"percent_change_24h":1.63,"percent_change_7d":8.91}},"last_updated":1531828567},"512":{"id":512,"name":"Stellar","symbol":"XLM","website_slug":"stellar","rank":7,"circulating_supply":18766530971,"total_supply":104125061584,"max_supply":null,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":0.231804,"volume_24h":49352700,"market_cap":4350156945,"percent_change_1h":-0.94,"percent_change_24h":0.8,"percent_change_7d":17.92}},"last_updated":1531828584},"2010":{"id":2010,"name":"Cardano","symbol":"ADA","website_slug":"cardano","rank":8,"circulating_supply":25927070538,"total_supply":31112483745,"max_supply":45000000000,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":0.152682,"volume_24h":86195700,"market_cap":3958596984,"percent_change_1h":0.16,"percent_change_24h":1.2,"percent_change_7d":15.48}},"last_updated":1531828594},"1720":{"id":1720,"name":"IOTA","symbol":"MIOTA","website_slug":"iota","rank":9,"circulating_supply":2779530283,"total_supply":2779530283,"max_supply":2779530283,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":1.06608,"volume_24h":45845200,"market_cap":2963201644,"percent_change_1h":-0.49,"percent_change_24h":0.44,"percent_change_7d":8.21}},"last_updated":1531828590},"825":{"id":825,"name":"Tether","symbol":"USDT","website_slug":"tether","rank":10,"circulating_supply":2707140346,"total_supply":3080109502,"max_supply":null,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":1.00215,"volume_24h":2728850000,"market_cap":2712960697,"percent_change_1h":0.11,"percent_change_24h":0.45,"percent_change_7d":-0.16}},"last_updated":1531828588},"1958":{"id":1958,"name":"TRON","symbol":"TRX","website_slug":"tron","rank":11,"circulating_supply":65748111645,"total_supply":99000000000,"max_supply":null,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":0.0367706,"volume_24h":191259000,"market_cap":2417597514,"percent_change_1h":0.03,"percent_change_24h":1.55,"percent_change_7d":8.49}},"last_updated":1531828593},"1376":{"id":1376,"name":"NEO","symbol":"NEO","website_slug":"neo","rank":12,"circulating_supply":65000000,"total_supply":100000000,"max_supply":100000000,"quotes":{"USD":{"price":36.2949,"volume_24h":128189
```

here is my code for the request

public ArrayList getCoin () {
        firstlist.clear();

```
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            Constants.URL_JSON, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


            try {

                JSONArray coinArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < coinArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject coinOBJ = coinArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    CoinMarketAPI coin = new CoinMarketAPI();


                   // coin.setId(coinOBJ.getString("id"));
                    //coin.setName(coinOBJ.getString("name"));
                    //coin.setSymbol(coinOBJ.getString("symbol"));
                    //coin.setWebsite_slug(coinOBJ.getString("website_slug"));
                   // coin.setRank(coinOBJ.getString("rank"));
                   // coin.setCirculating_supply(coinOBJ.getString("circulating_supply"));
                   // coin.setTotal_supply(coinOBJ.getString("total_supply"));
                   // coin.setQuotes(coinOBJ.getString("quotes"));
                   // coin.setUSD(coinOBJ.getString("USD"));
                   // coin.setPrice(coinOBJ.getString("price"));


                          Log.d(TAG, coin.getName());




                    firstlist.add(coin);


                }
```

**JSON**

```
{
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17008162.0, 
        "total_supply": 17008162.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 9024.09, 
                "volume_24h": 8765400000.0, 
                "market_cap": 153483184623.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -2.31, 
                "percent_change_24h": -4.18, 
                "percent_change_7d": -0.47
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1525137271
    }, 
    "1027": {
        "id": 1027, 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "website_slug": "ethereum", 
        "rank": 2, 
        "circulating_supply": 99151888.0, 
        "total_supply": 99151888.0, 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 642.399, 
                "volume_24h": 2871290000.0, 
                "market_cap": 63695073558.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -3.75, 
                "percent_change_24h": -7.01, 
                "percent_change_7d": -2.32
            }
        },
```

**NOTE** some lines are commented out to prevent further errors.

Im think the error is to do the jsonarray  response line but not to sure how to fix it. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your json is incomplete, use a json validator to make sure your json is valid: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: "data" is not a jsonArray because their bracket looks like "{ }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is object, not an array, so you can loop by iterator like this

```
JSONObject coinArray = response.getJSONObject("data");
Iterator<String> iter = coinArray.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object coinOBJ = coinArray.get(key);

        CoinMarketAPI coin = new CoinMarketAPI();
        coin.setId(coinOBJ.getString("id"));
        coin.setName(coinOBJ.getString("name"));
        coin.setSymbol(coinOBJ.getString("symbol"));
        coin.setWebsite_slug(coinOBJ.getString("website_slug"));
        coin.setRank(Integer.parseInt(coinOBJ.getString("rank")));
        coin.setCirculating_supply(coinOBJ.getString("circulating_supply"));
        coin.setTotal_supply(coinOBJ.getString("total_supply"));
        coin.setQuotes(coinOBJ.getString("quotes"));
        coin.setUSD(coinOBJ.getString("USD"));
        coin.setPrice(coinOBJ.getString("price"));

        Log.d(TAG, coin.getName());
        firstlist.add(coin);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Comment: which getString?

Comment: coin.setRank(coinOBJ.getString("rank"));  these getStrings

Comment: please check updated answer and you have to set your `CoinMarketAPI coin` as you want.  because I don't know your `coin.setRank()` is accept long, int or String

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it for you. What I did is that "data" was a JsonObject and has multiple objects Inside itself. so I converted data Into Json array by jsonObject.names(); Now I will get each object inside data through for loop.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.names(); 
      Log.e(tag,jsonArray.toString());
              for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

        JSONObject getObjectFromJsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));
        CoinMarketAPI coin=new CoinMarketAPI();
        coin.setId(getObjectFromJsonArray.getString("id"));
        coin.setName(getObjectFromJsonArray.getString("name"));
        coin.setSymbol(getObjectFromJsonArray.getString("symbol"));
        coin.setWebsite_slug(getObjectFromJsonArray.getString("website_slug"));
        coin.setRank(getObjectFromJsonArray.getString("rank"));
        coin.setCirculating_supply(getObjectFromJsonArray.getString("circulating_supply"));
        coin.setTotal_supply(getObjectFromJsonArray.getString("total_supply"));
        JSONObject qoutes = getObjectFromJsonArray.getJSONObject("quotes");
        JSONObject  USD   = qoutes.getJSONObject("USD");
        coin.setPrice(USD.getString("price"));
        firstlist.add(coin);
        }
```

Comment: error: variable coinOBJ might not have been initialized

Comment: jsut replace coinOBJ by getObjectFromJsonArray

Comment: sorry which one?

Comment: Is it work? I have tested my answer and It works for me

Comment: your loop solution worked but I get a error 

err: org.json.JSONException: No value for price

Comment: also E/coinActivity: ["1","1027","52","1831","1765","2","512","2010","1720","825","1958","1376","328","131","1321","873","1839","2011","1808","1904","1437","1684","1896","372","1214","1168","2469","2099","2566","463","2083","1700","109","1042","1518","1230","693","1697","1567","1104","74","1866","2222","2603","1455","1274","1925","2087","1343","2021","1759","1789","2606","1903","2349","2608","1229","2062","2405","1934

Comment: It's shows the key Id, through these key id will get object inside data. Ignore it, It's not an error.

Comment: what about the no value for price I try to get a double instead of string but it did not change the outcome

Comment: put a if statment round price and my log is 
**no price**

`if (jsonObject.has("price")){coin.setPrice(getObjectFromJsonArray.getDouble("price"));
                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "No price");
                        }`

Comment: hey it's the full answer. Hopefully It will help you